# Does this proof need to be more rigorously proven?

Tags: analysis

So I have a problem where I am to determine the limit or prove it doesn't exist.

The problem is:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x)\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) $$

My proof is as follows (I'm pretty confident about this):

For all $ x \ne 0, -1 \le \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \le 1$.

Hence, $-\sin(x) \le \sin(x)\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \le \sin(x) $

As $x$ goes to zero, so does $-\sin(x)$ and $\sin(x)$.

So by squeeze lemma, the original problem has a limit of $0$.

So my question is, is this sufficient enough where everything seems trivial? The main part I'm worried about is the $\sin(x) = 0$ as $x$ goes to $0$. Do I need to prove this? I just assumed it was ok because $\sin(0) = 0$.

Comment: you multiply both sides by $\sin x$ even without knowing when it is positive or negative?

Comment: Aww, I thought I had it... I overlooked the fact that it could be negative. So I can't use the squeeze lemma here?

Comment: Of course you can still use squeeze lemma. I am halfway to an answer but  @Dr. MV did it ahead of me. See his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost correct.  Instead of writing things as in the OP, we can simply write

$$0\le |\sin(x)\cos(1/x)|=|\sin(x)|\,|\cos(1/x)|\le |\sin(x)|\,(1)=|\sin(x)|$$

And now apply the squeeze theorem.

And if there are any doubts on the limit of the sine function, recall that we have

$$|\sin(x)|\le |x|$$

for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your inequalities need to be flipped based on what half of the plane we are in. We have that
$$-\sin(x) < \sin(x)\cos(1/x) < \sin(x) \qquad \forall x> 0$$
$$\sin(x) < \sin(x)\cos(1/x) < -\sin(x) \qquad \forall x< 0$$
Can you see why this is? Now, this doesn't really affect your squeezing argument, so you are still fine.

Comment: Good post!  (+1)

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank! However, I must say your inequality argument is much cleaner! The fact that $|xy|=|x|\,|y|$ seems to me to be one of the most under-used and yet powerful theorems in basic inequalities!

Comment: Well, you're welcome and thank you also!