# Why does $\lim_{x \to 0} |{\sin (x)}|\cos (1/x) = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

The answer $0$ was obtained by plugging it into Wolfram. I'm kind of split on the answer.

On one hand, the answer Wolfram gives makes sense because the limit of $|{\sin x}|$ evaluates to $0$. Anything multiplied by $0$ is $0$, hence why the entire limit is $0$.

But the caveat here is that the $\cos (1/x)$ part of the limit is DNE. As far as I'm aware, the rule of multiplying any number by $0$ to get a result of $0$ doesn't apply because the result of it isn't a number!

I thought about using the squeeze theorem to prove it, but I'm not sure if it works.

Comment: The key is note that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}|\sin(x)|=0$ and $\cos(1/x)$ is a bounded function over $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0 \}$. What is the result of calculating the limit of a bounded function times a function that thends to zero?

Comment: Do you know anything about 'sandwich' or squezzzzzzz?

Comment: See [The problem is $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x)\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2231782/318073) and [Proving that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \sin(x)\cos(\tfrac1x) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/431079/318073).

Comment: When you calculate the limit of $f(x)$ as $x \to a$, you only consider values of $x$ near to but not equal to $a$.  Look carefully at the formal definition of a limit to see this. The limit can exist even if $f(a)$ is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $x\rightarrow 0$, the outputs of $\cos(1/x)$ will oscillate wildly between $-1$ and $1$. But when multiplied by $\lvert \sin(x)\rvert$ that oscillation will happen at smaller and smaller amplitudes since $\sin(x)$ will tend to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\cos(\frac{1}{x}) \le 1$. Therefore

$|\sin(x)\cos(1/x)|\le |\sin(x)|$

Answer (score 0):

Be careful! *'Anything multiplied by zero is zero'* is certainly true, but the rule does not hold in limits. One term *convergent* to zero is not the same as one term *equal* zero. As a counterexample consider $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(x\cdot\frac 1x\right)$ which equals $1$ despite the first term $x\to 0$.